# http_build_query(): Parameter 1 ERROR Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Created app medium poster

http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object.

Code:

Error: in line 75

```html
   $url .= (strpos($url , '?') !== false ? '&' : '?') . http_build_query($data);
```

why? this error in my code, check please

Answer (score 1):

make sure $data is an array or object. find the example below

```
$data = ['id'=>25, 'name'=>'test']; //array
$url = "http://google.com";

$url .= (strpos($url , '?') !== false ? '&' : '?') . http_build_query($data);

echo $url;

//Output: http://google.com?id=25&name=test
```